# Memory allocation code error

Tags: c, linux, xubuntu

I'm developing a client-server program and when and I'm trying to implement a user linked list using this structure:

```
typedef struct user {
    char username[50];
    int user_pid;
    struct user *next;
} user_list;
```

I'm trying figure out what's wrong with the code, because the compiler doesn't give me any error, but when I try to user to print the users list, it simply doesn't display anything.

AddUser function:

```
AddUser(user_list *head, req req)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = malloc(sizeof(user_list));

        if (head == NULL) 
            fprintf(stdout,"[SERVER] Error memory allocation ");

        strcpy(head->username, req.str);
        head->user_pid = req.client_pid;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {   
        user_list *current = head;

        while (current->next != NULL) 
            current = current->next;

        current->next = malloc(sizeof(user_list));
        strcpy(current->next->username, req.str);
        current->next->user_pid = req.client_pid;
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }
    num_users++;
}
```

Main Function (short version)

```
int Main()
{
struct request req;
struct answer ans;
user_list *head = NULL;

do{

    read(fifo_1, &req, sizeof(req)); // Read client request

    if(strcasecmp(req.str, "adduser") == 0) 
    {               
        AddUser(head, req);
        strcpy(ans.str, "User added with success! You're logged!");
    }

    if(strcasecmp(req.str, "users") == 0) // Print on the screen the users list
    {
        user_list *current = head;

        while (current != NULL) 
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", current->username);
            fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", current->user_pid);
            current = current->next;
        }

    }
}while(strcmp(req.str,"exit") != 0);
}
```

Comment: @pzaenger my bad, i wrote this part just to show here, and i forgot. I already edit the post.

Comment: The variable `head` of the `main` function is not update in AddUser. You need to pass a reference to the pointer or a pointer to the pointer to be able to update inside and reflect outside. Use this: `void AddUser(user_list*& head, req req)` or `void AddUser(user_list** head, req req)`

Comment: `int Main()` isn't conventional C either (C is case-sensitive and it is `int main()`).  Please review how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.  It will get you better help than non-compilable code will.  You need to error check the `read()` call.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, as i said below, i just put here the most important parts of the code, related with the linked list. Perhaps i've some mistakes, but the my code is working perfectly, except this part (memory allocation). But i'll follow your advice! Thank's.

Comment: We can't debug what we can't see -- though I think NetVipeC has probably nailed the real problem.  When you're asking for help, please be courteous and ask questions where the code shown compiles (unless, of course, the whole problem is that it doesn't compile but should), and preferably the code should be complete so that we can compile it ourselves (and it should be short, and should reproduce the problem on your system).  Yes, there are conflicting goals between reproducible and minimal, but working on the minimal reproduction often helps you solve the problem anyway.

Comment: @NetVipeC Should i change something inside the function AddUser? Because after i change using your tip, the gcc showed me some errors.

Comment: Test @RSahu answer that contain another version of the same fix. Without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is really difficult test anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting together what others have already pointed out in comments:

1. Change `main`. Instead of

   ```
   int Main()
   ```

   use

   ```
   int main()
   ```
2. The value of `head`, doesn't change in `main` when you change it in `AddUser`. Here's one solution. Return `head` from AddUser.

   ```
   user_list* AddUser(user_list *head, req req)
   {
       if(head == NULL)
       {
           head = malloc(sizeof(user_list));

           if (head == NULL) 
               fprintf(stdout,"[SERVER] Error memory allocation ");

           strcpy(head->username, req.str);
           head->user_pid = req.client_pid;
           head->next = NULL;
       }
       else
       {   
           user_list *current = head;

           while (current->next != NULL) 
               current = current->next;

           current->next = malloc(sizeof(user_list));
           strcpy(current->next->username, req.str);
           current->next->user_pid = req.client_pid;
           current->next->next = NULL;
       }
       num_users++;
       return head;
   }
   ```
3. Capture the return value of `AddUser` in `main`. Instead of just

   ```
   AddUser(head, req);
   ```

   use

   ```
   head = AddUser(head, req);
   ```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank's, and i'm sorry to be a beginner, and SSCCE concept is something new for me.

Comment: @MarcodeBarbosa, you are welcome. No need to apologize for being a beginner. We all started from there. Live and learn :)